Finding eigenvalues of this matrix with $0$'s and $1$'s

Consider this $5\times 5$ matrix over $\mathbb R$ and find its eigenvalues.$$A=\pmatrix{1&0&0&0&1\\ 0&1&1&1&0\\0&1&1&1&0\\0&1&1&1&0\\1&0&0&0&1}$$

So the standard solution does something like this...
$\pmatrix{1&0&0&0&1\\ 0&1&1&1&0\\0&1&1&1&0\\0&1&1&1&0\\1&0&0&0&1}\sim \pmatrix{1&1&0&0&0\\ 1&1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&1&1\\0&0&1&1&1\\0&0&1&1&1} \tag*{}$
There was no justification given. They obtained the second matrix by $R_2\leftrightarrow R_5, C_2\leftrightarrow C_5$. I can find the eigenvalues of the resulting block matrices very easily by some standard tricks. However, as far as I know, row or column operations do not preserve similarity. So how does this work?
Edit: $\leftrightarrow$ is symbol for "swap".

the two matrices are permutation similar. In particular consider $E_2 A E_2= E_2 A E_2^{-1}$ for a well chosen type 2 elementary matrix.  If you know what a graph isomorphism is: this amounts to relabeling nodes 2 and 5 of a graph.

@user8675309 Sorry, I do not know graph theory.

@user8675309 But I think I am getting the explanation using type 2 elementary matrix. Performing $R_2\leftrightarrow R_5$ is same left multiplying by a permutation matrix $P$. And then performing the same permutation on columns means to right multiply $P$. And since this permutation is a transposition, $P=P^{-1}$. Thus, $PAP=PAP^{-1} \sim A$. Is that right?

Hint: if $A$ is the matrix of an endomorphism $T$ of $\Bbb R^5$ is some basis $(e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4,e_5)$, what is the matrix of $T$ in the basis $(e_1,e_5,e_2,e_3,e_4)$?

Shouldn't the new basis be $(e_1, e_5, e_3, e_4, e_2)$ since the associated permutation is $(25)$? Edit: It seems both work.

$$A=\pmatrix{1&0&0&0&1\\ 0&1&1&1&0\\0&1&1&1&0\\0&1&1&1&0\\1&0&0&0&1}$$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
$$ $$
the columns of $W,$  below,   are eigenvectors of $A. $  What is the product $AW \; \; ?$
$$ W =
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & -1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & -1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\ 
1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
Note that the columns of $W$ are pairwise orthogonal, thus linearly independent. One could easily create an orthogonal matrix $O$  by dividing each column by the square root of the sum of the five squares  of its elements.
About linear independence:  one may check that the columns are pairwise orthogonal, but they are not normalized in length. Call the columns $c_1, c_2, c_3, c_4, c_5$  Say I have coefficients $b_j$  such that $b_1 c_1 + b_2 c_2 + b_3 c_3 +  b_4 c_4 + b_5 c_5 = 0$  as a column vector.   Well, take the ordinary dot product with $c_1.$ This is the dot product of $c_1$ with the zero vector and must be zero.  The outcome is $b_1 (c_1 \cdot c_1) = b_1 \cdot 2,$   and this being zero forces $b_1 = 0.$  Next take the dot product with $c_2,$   the outcome is again $2 b_2 = 0$  Then $b_3, b_4, b_5.$  The relation   $b_1 c_1 + b_2 c_2 + b_3 c_3 +  b_4 c_4 + b_5 c_5 = 0$  forces all $b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4, b_5 = 0;$  this is linear independence.
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

Isn't finding eigenvectors harder than the original problem itself? Anyways, the columns of $AW$ are scaled version of columns of $W$, scaled by factors of $2,0,3,0,0$ respectively.

@Nothingspecial  and those scaling factors are the eigenvalues: 2,0,3,0,0.
